# Cannot insert images using PHPExcel & Codeigniter

Tags: php, phpexcel, export-to-excel, worksheet

i have some problem in this part. There is no exported images in worksheet.

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
              $objDrawing->setName("logo_sci");
              $objDrawing->setDescription("logo_sci");
              $objDrawing->setPath('./assets/images/sucofindo_logo.PNG');
              $objDrawing->setCoordinates('C6');
              $objDrawing->setHeight(120); 
              $objDrawing->setWidth(120);
              $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

need help! Thanks..

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the correct path for your current working directory?

Comment: may be you have to save it by $objDrawing->save();

Comment: Yeah i'm really sure @MarkBaker,

Comment: It doesn't work @Fisherman But thanks by the way..

Comment: What Writer are you using then?

Comment: Did you try with full path ?

Comment: this is the writter that i used to $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, 'Excel5');
  $objWriter->save('php://output'); @MarkBaker

Comment: using fullpath doesn't work too @KevinLabécot

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me:

```
    if (file_exists('includes/temp/signatures/'.$id.'.jpg')) {
        $objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
        $objDrawing->setName('Customer Signature');
        $objDrawing->setDescription('Customer Signature');
        //Path to signature .jpg file
        $signature = FCPATH.'/includes/temp/signatures/'.$id.'.jpg';    
        $objDrawing->setPath($signature);
        $objDrawing->setOffsetX(8);                     //setOffsetX works properly
        $objDrawing->setCoordinates('E38');             //set image to cell E38
        $objDrawing->setHeight(75);                     //signature height  
        $objDrawing->setWorksheet($this->excel->getActiveSheet());  //save      
    }
```

As you can see all is different from your code is the setPath(). Needs to be root path to your file

Note: I'm using PHPExcel as a library of Codeigniter.
See here how: http://fally.ro/using-phpexcel-class-with-codeigniter/